# What is $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I don't really understand what $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$ is. I get what $\Bbb R^2$ is and I get what $ \|\cdot\|_2$ is (the euclidian norm). I understand the definitions. However I don't understand what $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$ is, in the sense that I have to solve excercises where I have to find different examples in $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$ of sets which might have different properties (open, closed, compact etc) and I wouldn't know where to start because I don't know what that means. That means that I have seen and reseen all the definitions and I understand them, however I am clearly missing something since I can't in any way put it into practice.

If someone would help me I would be deeply grateful. Please no rude/childish answers.

Edit: To be more precise, I don't understand what this norm does to $\Bbb R^2$ specifically. If I have to find examples in $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$ then I have to consider this norm, but what am I considering exactly, what "rules" does this norm impose?

Comment: $(\mathbb{R}^2, \|.\|_2)$ simply means that you consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the euclidean norm, that is you consider the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is induced by the euclidean norm.

Comment: This notation makes sense, since in order to ask and answer questions about openness or closedness of sets (or any topological property really), we first need to declare the topology that we consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, there are vectors of numbers $(x_1, x_2)$, and rules about how to add, 
$$
(x_1,x_2) + (y_1+y_2) = (x_1+y_1, x_2 +y_2)
$$
and do scalar multiplication
$$
r(x_1,x_2) = (rx_1,rx_2),
$$
and so on. That is what the symbol $\mathbb{R}^2$ is: the set of objects and a structure of how the objects combine. There are other axioms, like associativity, identity, etc.  These are all algebraic properties about combining and stretching vectors. Altogether these rules make $\mathbb{R}^2$ a vector space.

The norm is a different object. It takes a vector, $x$, and assigns a single number to it, which is its length. The Euclidean norm,
$$
||x|| = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}
$$
is just one way to assign length. Another is the supnorm,
$$
||x|| = \max \{|x_1|,|x_2|\},
$$
or
$$
||x|| = \left( x_1^p+x_2^p \right)^{1/p}.
$$
These are all just different ways of assigning an idea of ``length'' to a vector, that has nothing in particular to do with the underlying algebraic structure of the space.

Once you have a norm, you can define open sets. The open ball with radius $\delta$ is
$$
B_\delta(x) = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x|| < \delta \}.
$$
See how it's just the norm in there, not any particular norm? You can use the Euclidean one, that's great. That gives you circles. A set is open iff it is a union of open balls. The set $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open, as well as $\varnothing$.

A set is closed if its complement is open. Alternatively, a set is closed if every convergent sequence in the set converges to an element of the set.

A set is compact iff it is closed and bounded, by the Heine-Borel theorem. That means its complement is open, and there is an open ball that contains the set with finite radius.

So once you have a norm $||\cdot||$, you get open balls.  Once you have the open balls, you can define open sets, then closed sets, then compact sets.

Comment: the answer was really helpful. Adding up to my question, what would then exactly mean to have a subset of this space $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$ . Let's say we have the subset A={x*y=1} in this vector space with the euclidean norm, what does this exactly mean? Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space. You can add a structure of normed vector space by adding a norm, which is for example $\|.\|_2$. But it is not the only norm on this space. So you say $(\mathbb{R}^2,\|.\|_2)$ to say "the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the norm $\|.\|_2$. Plenty of other norms exists. The conditions open, compact, closed, *etc.* are topological conditions, so depend on the norm you choose.

To be honest, in the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$, these topological statements don't depend on the norm because of the finite dimension (Riesz's theorem) but it is not a trivial result.

Comment: One might also add, that you can define topologies on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are not induced by a norm.

Comment: Yes. To pe precise, there is a unique normed topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but many others not induced by any norm

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer, but what does it mean to add a norm, what does this norm do precisely? I mean if I have to find examples of sets in $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$ then I have to consider this norm, but what am I considering exactly? which conditions do I have to fufill?

Comment: The sets are sets of $\mathbb R^2$. You can read that as "find the sets in $\mathbb R^2$ such that when you define the topology with the 2-norm, then ...". This notation is just as a list of two things.

Comment: A norm is a function $N$ (here $\|.\|_2$) verifying some axioms (positivity, triangle inequality and homogeneity). It provides a way to measure distances in a vector spaces, and thus provides a topology (a way to talk about "open" and "closed" sets). If you change the norm, you change the distance, and maybe a set which was open for a norm would not for another.